# Unable to print the report completely

Tags: forms, reporting-services, deployment, ssrs-2008, subform

```
   I have created a form based report in ssrs using sub-forms and Tablix (Notes)
```

but when I deploy the report I cannot see entire form 
and cannot even print the report completely.

[image: Tablix properties]

I have identified that only data in sub-report format is getting printed and tablix data is getting lost. And Notes doesn't exist anywhere in my dataset.

Any idea how to overcome this situation?

Can someone please help with this I am struggling to get this done since long time.

Comment: Do you have a filter in your tablix or group or do you have a visibility statement that could be throwing it off?

Comment: Spencer - Thanks for quick reply.. I see there are no filters and visibility is set to show..

Comment: The screenshot and description don't seem to explain your problem very well, so it's difficult to suggest a solution...there could be hidden items, or collapsible items, or other items.  Also, when you say you cannot "print the report completely," are you "printing" to the screen, or trying to export it to a file, or actually printing from the report viewer to an actual printer?  What kind of server are you deploying your report to?  Are you deploying all of the reports and sub-reports to the same place?